# Invalid procedure call or argument on split mac excel vba

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I am not sure why but this `cet = Split(strCSV, " - ")` causes Run time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

```
   strCSV = Trim(cWk.Range("P" & i)): dt = CDate(CLng(cWk.Range("H" & i)))
```

> where    str = "Cap Style:Snapback - CD / Number:07 / Color:First Avenger(+S$1.50) / Box:none - Only Purchase 3 caps and above - Free Box "

Following code works perfectly on windows but it throws error on the above mentioned line

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub Get_Data()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim fName, wkB2 As Workbook, cWk As Worksheet, xWk As Worksheet, frowC As Long, i As Long, j As Long, ch As String, num As String
Dim strCSV As String, dt As Date, shtName As String, cet, temp As String, rng As Range, cel As Range, cl As String, rw As Long, toF As String

On Error GoTo Err
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename
If fName <> False Then
Set wkB2 = Workbooks.Open(fName): Set cWk = wkB2.Worksheets(1): frowC = cWk.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Cap Style:Baseball - CC / Number:04 / Color:Grey(+S$2) / Box:none - Only Purchase 3 caps and above - Free Box
'Cap Style:SnapBack - CC / Number:04 / Color:Grey(+S$1.50) / Box:none - Only Purchase 3 caps and above - Free Box

For i = 2 To frowC
    strCSV = Trim(cWk.Range("P" & i)): dt = CDate(CLng(cWk.Range("H" & i)))
    If strCSV <> "" And IsDate(dt) Then
     'ERROR  cet = Split(strCSV, " - "): temp = cet(LBound(cet)): cet = Split(temp, ":"): shtName = Trim(cet(UBound(cet)))
        For Each xWk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If shtName = Trim(xWk.Name) Then

        Set rng = xWk.Range("E3:BD3")
            For Each cel In rng
                If cel.Value = dt Then
                    cet = Split(cel.Address, "$"): cl = cet(UBound(cet) - 1): Exit For
                End If
            Next cel

        cet = Split(strCSV, "Number:"): temp = cet(UBound(cet)): cet = Split(temp, "/"): num = Trim(cet(LBound(cet)))
        cet = Split(strCSV, " / "): temp = cet(LBound(cet)): cet = Split(temp, " - "): ch = Trim(cet(UBound(cet))): ch = ch & "-" & num
        Debug.Print "Ch is " & ch
        Set rng = xWk.Range("A1:A" & xWk.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            For Each cel In rng
                If cel.Value = ch Then
                    rw = cel.Row: Exit For
                End If
            Next cel

        cet = Split(strCSV, "Color:"): temp = cet(UBound(cet)): cet = Split(temp, "("): toF = Trim(cet(LBound(cet)))
            For j = rw To rw - 10 Step -1
                If Trim(xWk.Range("B" & j)) = toF Then
                    rw = j: Exit For
                End If
            Next j

        Debug.Print "Address is: " & cl & rw & " for row  " & i
        xWk.Range(cl & rw) = cWk.Range("O" & i)

            Exit For
            End If
        Next xWk

    End If
Next i

wkB2.Close False
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Mac Excel are you using?

Comment: It doesn't works on mac '11 v14.6.4

Comment: The Split function was introduced in VB6.  If your mac excel vba is using an earlier version then the function will not be available.  I would go into the VBE object browser, select the VBA library from the dropdown and search through the available functions.

Comment: Yes you are right split is NA in that version!! do you have a work around or suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update: SplitString now handle multi-character delimiters.

We conclude that older versions of Mac Office use the equivalent of VB5.  Since the Split function was introduced in VB6.  An `Invalid procedure call or argument` is being thrown because the Split function is not available in VB5.

The workaround would be to create a custom function that works like Spli.

### Split Replacement Function

```
Function SplitString(Text As String, Delimiter As String)
    Dim arr() As String, s As String
    Dim i As Long, iEnd As Long, iStart As Long, length As Long

    length = Len(Delimiter)

    ReDim Preserve arr(0)

    iStart = 1
    Do
        iEnd = InStr(Mid(Text, iStart), Delimiter) - 1

        If iEnd = -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = Mid(Text, iStart)
            Exit Do
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = Mid(Text, iStart, iEnd)
            iStart = iStart + iEnd + length
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until iStart = 0

    SplitString = arr
End Function
```

### Here are the tests that I ran

```
Sub BatchTest()
    Dim strCSV As String, Temp As String, Delimiter As String
    Dim a
    strCSV = "Cap Style Snapback - CD / Number 07 / Color First Avenger(+S$1.50) / Box none - Only Purchase 3 caps and above - Free Box"
    a = SplitString(strCSV, "/")

    TestSplit strCSV, " / "
    TestSplit strCSV, " /"
    TestSplit strCSV, "/"
    TestSplit strCSV, " Color First"

End Sub

Sub TestSplit(Text As String, Delimiter As String)
    Dim arr As Variant, sReplcement As String

    arr = SplitString(Text, Delimiter)
    sReplcement = Replace(Text, Delimiter, "|")
    Debug.Print sReplcement
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
    Debug.Print sReplcement = Join(arr, "|")

End Sub
```

### The Results of the tests

[image]

---

```
Sub TestRegEx()
    MsgBox RegexExtract("sdi 99090 dfddf sdi 5666", "(sdi \d+)", ", ") = "sdi 99090, sdi 5666"

End Sub

Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String, _
                      Optional seperator As String = "") As String

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.count - 1
    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.count - 1
        result = result & seperator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j)
    Next
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

RegexExtract = result

End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to split using more than 1 char as delimiter it fails there

Comment: Thanks but the split function is still not accurate.

Comment: This is the raw text : `Cap Style:Snapback - CD / Number:07 / Color:First Avenger(+S$1.50) / Box:none - Only Purchase 3 caps and above - Free Box 
` this is the code `cet = SplitString(strCSV, "Number:"): temp = cet(UBound(cet)): cet = SplitString(temp, "/"): num = Trim(cet(LBound(cet)))
        cet = SplitString(strCSV, " / "): temp = cet(LBound(cet)): cet = SplitString(temp, " - "): ch = Trim(cet(UBound(cet))): ch = ch & "-" & num` and the `ch` should be `CD` and `num` should be `07` but it returns `CD - 07 \` extra `\`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works on windows but throws `Out of Memory` error on mac. is there any way  I can download the real source code of split function ? I upgraded the excel to '15 on mac but still the split function is NA on mac such a shame :(

Comment: I appended a test for RegEx to my answer.  Could you try it out.  If a Msgbox shows true then RegEx is the way to go.

Comment: @VincentG Your probably right.  I can't believe that my function throws the out of memory error.    Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No, I don't see why it would raise an out of memory error, but I don't know mac.

Comment: Maybe if i is not initialized by default to 0 on mac? Then the first Redim might fail? try to set i=0 before the loop?

Comment: I initialized  i=0 before iStart =1 same error no luck.

Comment: Did you run my test?